# Responsive playing card design with css html

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I was trying to create a queue of playing card that is responsive to display width.

[image: Queue of card that i like to be responsive]

I want this queue to be fit to display width so that no card get lost from display. I want to cover conventional width of phone, tablet and desktop.

I also like to align this queue to center so that it does not look bad.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fahadbillah/GeX8n/)

```
<div> 
    <img src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg" alt="">
</div>

div{
    width:100%;
}
img{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
}
.rest{
    margin-left: -102px;
}
```

Comment: Is number of the cards fixed?

Comment: yes fixed. 21 cards. @HashemQolami

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a perfect fit for the new [Flexbox model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)!

Use `display:inline-flex` on your wrapping div, and remove the `display:inline-block` on `img`:

```
div{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-flex;
}
img{
    height: 200px;
}
.rest{
    margin-left: -102px;
    /*flex-grow:1;*/          /* Bonus : all available width is occupied */
}
```

The `flex-grow:1` causes your `img` to grow, while space is available, but they are deformed.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GeX8n/2/), and some references and extras :

- [Compatibility chart](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) on Caniuse.com
- [MDN tutorial on Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)
- [Flex tutorial on CSSTricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [Flex reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Comment: @Bigood.... you just save the day.... this is exactly what i was looking for. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want better browser compatibility, you can do it [***this way***](http://jsfiddle.net/2C4Cv/)

- Have all your cards have `class="rest"`
- Update your CSS to this

```
div{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;     /* If you want it centered */
    padding-right:102px;   /* Inverse the value of the card's right margin */
    box-sizing:border-box; /* Because we want the padding to be included in the width calculation */
}
img{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
}
.rest{
    margin-right: -102px; /* Use margin-right instead of margin-left */
}
```

Comment: that's also a good option but i wanted to keep all the cards in single row. thanks btw